# How to Create Strategy that is based on one ticker but trades another ticker?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

how do I create a strategy that is based on one ticker but trades a different ticker?

e.g. When the VIX crosses above 35 buy SPY and when the VIX crosses below 15 sell the SPY.

I can't seem to figure out how to code that in Pine Script and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that don’t show what you’ve tried are generally more difficult to answer - people often skip right over them. So show your code for better answers. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. To learn more about helping us help you, please start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. TV doesn't allow running strategies from one ticker on another.  You could possibly try using a security request to pull in VIX data to evaluate in a strategy placed on SPY.

A better method is not using TV strategies at all and instead build indicators that send alerts to backtesting software you are running or a service you are paying for.  That way you can create order logic to trade multiple assets from one script.